# User-mapped section open error in Grails

Tags: grails, java-8, java

I am trying to build WAR file for a Grails application using IDEA 2017.1.4 on Windows 10.
I get the following error:

```
|Compiling 17 GSP files for package [AECommand]
.Error 
|WAR packaging error: G:\Dropbox\thePlatform\AETN\aetn-dd-custom-commands\target\classes\gsp\views.properties (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

The applications runs fine in IDEA and gives me the same error in PowerShell. And it ran and built fine using a terminal "grails war" command on my MacPro, which is currently not available to me.

MacPro and Windows IDEA project use JDK7.

When I try to run the app in PowerShell using JDK8, I get the folloing error which does have "Incompatible JVM?" message in it:

```
Oct 24, 2017 6:45:17 AM org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM copyMethod
SEVERE: Problems copying method. Incompatible JVM?
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM.copyMethod(JVM.java:134)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.createJavaMethod(OriginalClassInvoker.java:68)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredMethods(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:151)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1.run(CachedClass.java:84)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:79)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getMethods(CachedClass.java:250)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.populateMethods(MetaClassImpl.java:343)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.fillMethodIndex(MetaClassImpl.java:293)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3048)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.initialize(ExpandoMetaClass.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:176)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough setting JAVA_HOME to JDK7 and using the PowerShell solved the problem - JAR got built.